# Select option using python (spynner library)

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, spynner

I am trying to use the spynner library to select an option in html (need to use spynner, or a library that loads javascript).  However, I cannot get it to work, even with this solved example: [Using Spynner module in Python (need to select a Javascript element)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6146472/using-spynner-module-in-python-need-to-select-a-javascript-element).

Here is my example python code:

```
import time
import spynner
url = 'http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select'
br = spynner.Browser()
br.show()
br.load(url)
br.select("option[value='opel']")
time.sleep(2)
```

Here is the html code i'm nagging at:

```
<body>
<select>
<option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
<option value="saab">Saab</option>
<option value="opel">Opel</option>
<option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
</body>
```

Yikes! The python code will not select an option nor generate an error.  Can you please help = /

Answer (score -1):

You have 2 options, use javascript or use the click option.

Using the spynner option is simple.

```
br.click("option[value='Opel']")
```

If anything happens, use br.wait() to let the process finish.

If you use the javascript option, make sure that javascript is included or include it with br.load_js(). For jQuery that would be br.load_jQuery(True).

```
br.runjs("document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0].selectedIndex=1;")
```